# What does "劣勢を受け止める" mean?

Tags: meaning

I found this out of context. Looked everywhere and no answer to be found. [alc.co.jp](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E5%8A%A3%E5%8B%A2) offers a bunch of different meanings and is of not much help. Please help!

Comment: It's not a fixed phrase, so I think we could be of little help out of context.

Answer (score 2):

[受け止める]{うけとめる} can mean to catch or stop a blow, but it can also mean to accept or come to grips with something. Given that [劣勢]{れっせい} means something along the lines of inferiority or an unfavorable/disadvantaged situation, then without further context the best guess I can field is that it means "to accept an unfavorable situation."

Comment: so "to accept defeat" / "to come to terms with" perhaps?

Comment: @galki It wouldn't mean anything about "defeat", but more like to "accept the fact that this isn't a good situation".